# Finding a meteor user on the server

Tags: mongodb, meteor

The following server method is throwing duplicate key errors because the users are not being found. A typical query is: {services: {facebook: {id: 'XXXX'}}}

```
Meteor.methods
  getUser: (query, data = {}) ->
    user = Meteor.users.findOne(query)
    return user if user?
    user = _.extend(data, query)
    user._id = Meteor.users.insert user
    return user
```

It is my understanding that server methods have access to all documents in collections so why wouldn't the user be found but the insert fail due to a duplicate facebook id?

This works perfectly on my osx dev environment but fails on my ubuntu server (bundled) and running with NODE_ENV=production.

Here is the log output:

```
data:    { services: { facebook: { id: 'xxxx' } } } (the query provided to getUser)
data:    undefined (the result of findOne)
data:    Exception while invoking method 'getUser' MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: thunderstruck.users.$services.facebook.id_1  dup key: { : "xxxx" }
data:        at Db.wrap (/home/jeremy/deploy/thunderstruck/releases/20121105202012/bundle/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1904:11)
data:        at null.<anonymous> (/home/jeremy/deploy/thunderstruck/releases/20121105202012/bundle/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:320:26)
data:        at g (events.js:192:14)
data:        at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
data:        at Db._callHandler (/home/jeremy/deploy/thunderstruck/releases/20121105202012/bundle/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1439:25)
data:        at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/home/jeremy/deploy/thunderstruck/releases/20121105202012/bundle/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:425:30)
data:        at MongoReply.parseBody (/home/jeremy/deploy/thunderstruck/releases/20121105202012/bundle/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:127:5)
data:        at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/home/jeremy/deploy/thunderstruck/releases/20121105202012/bundle/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:384:22)
data:        at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
data:        at _connect (/home/jeremy/deploy/thunderstruck/releases/20121105202012/bundle/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:136:13)
```

Comment: I just got it working by formatting the query like this: {"services.facebook.id": "xxxx"} Seems the nesting was too deep. I tried various queries on the server using node-inspector and found that queries nested 3 deep always returned undefined. Still unclear as to why the deep nesting works on OSX and fails on Linux.

Answer (score 14):

Those are different MongoDB queries, and you definitely want the dotted-style that you switched to.  See the [Mongo Dot Notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) documentation.

```
Meteor.users.find({"services.facebook.id": "foo"})
```

will return any document that has the embedded property you're looking for with value `foo`.

```
Meteor.users.find({services: {facebook: {id: "foo"}}})
```

only matches documents with *exactly* that structure.  If the embedded facebook document has other fields, it won't match.  It's likely that the document in your production DB has more fields and so you weren't getting a match.